# N-Queens Backtracking/Recursion Logic Errors?

Tags: c++, recursion, backtracking, n-queens

I'm trying to solve this problem as a practice exercise for my upcoming test. It requires me to code a program in C++ that asks for input of "board size" (nxn) and "number of queens" and then performs the 'n-queens' problem.

**This n-queens problem differs from the "normal" n-queens problem** in that the number of queens and board size can be varied, and if a board is not completely filled up, open spaces are substituted.

An example output for input of size '8' and queen number '4' can be seen below:

```
O.......
..O.....
....O...
.O......
...­-..­.-
........
...­-.-..
...­-.­.-.
```

where 'O' represents a space that is occupied by a queen, '.' represents a space that is blocked by another queen, and '-' represents a space that *could* be occupied by another queen if the user inputted a higher number of queens (i.e. an open space).

The thing is, I've coded out the problem and it's giving me **EXTREMELY** inconsistent results. (example: inputting 4,4 works, 5,5 works, 6,6 *doesn't* work, 7,7 works, 8,8 *doesn't* work, 2,1 *doesn't* work.... the list goes on and on). I've found that the culprit is the combination of the 'for' loop and the recursion going back down the stack after it's done, causing several errors based on the situation. My question is, how would I fix the recursion loop so that it is still able to backtrack whilst also not unnecessarily causing errors? I am new to the idea of 'backtracking' coupled with recursion; what can I do to improve my method of backtracking in the future?

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void readBoard(char board[100][100], int size);
void printBoard(char board[100][100], int size);
bool findOpenSpot(char board[100][100], int row, int col, int size);
bool nQueenSolver(char board[100][100], int row, int size, int queenNumber);

int main()
{
    int queenNumber;
    int size;
    char b[100][100];
    cout << "What size board do you want?" << endl;
    cin >> size;
    readBoard(b, size);
    printBoard(b, size);
    cout << "How many queens do you want to place?" << endl;
    cin >> queenNumber;
    if (queenNumber > size)
    {
        cout << "Impossible." << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    if (nQueenSolver(b, 0, size, queenNumber) == true)
    {
        printBoard(b, size);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Impossible." << endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
bool nQueenSolver(char board[100][100], int row, int size, int queenNumber)
{
    if (row >= size)
    {
        return true;
    }

    for (int j=0; j<size; j++)
    {
        if (findOpenSpot(board, row, j, size) == true)
        {
            if (queenNumber >= 0)
            {
                board[row][j] = 'Q';
                cout << "Subtracting one queen." << endl;
            }
            else if (queenNumber < 0)
            {
                board[row][j] = '-'; //If all queens have already been placed, start showing open slots.
            }
            if (nQueenSolver(board, row+1, size, queenNumber) == true) //Recursion to cycle down the rows
            {
                return true; 
            }
            board[row][j] = '.'; //Backtracking if needed.
        }

    }
    return false;
}

bool findOpenSpot(char board[100][100], int row, int col, int size)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<col; i++)
    {
        if (board[row][i] == 'Q') //Checks if there's any queens to the left of the index
        {
            return false; //Not an open spot.
        }
    }
    i = row; j = col;
    while (i >= 0 && j >= 0)
    {
        if (board[i][j] == 'Q') //Checks if there's any queens in the upper left diagonal of the index
        {
            return false; 
        }
        i--; j--;
    }

    for (i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
        if (board[i][col] == 'Q') //Checks if there's any queens on top of the index
        {
            return false; 
        }
    }

    i = row; j = col;
    while (i >= 0 && j >= 0)
    {
        if (board[i][j] == 'Q') //Checks if there's any queens in the upper right diagonal of the index
        {
            return false;
        }
        i--; j++;
    }

    return true; //This index isn't threatened by a queen, go ahead and place one here!
    //Open spot!!
}


void readBoard(char board[100][100], int size)
{
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) //Puts in the size of the board into the array.
    {
        for (int j=0; j<size; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }
}

void printBoard(char board[100][100], int size)
{
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) //Prints the 'board' part of the array. (Doesn't print the entire array)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<size; j++)
        {
            cout << board[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I've also tried looking online for help and have found none (both on stackoverflow and google. Only pieces of information that I've already utilized). Any help would be greatly appreciated!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your "upper right" check in `findOpenSpot` (the last while loop) has an incorrect condition.  Since you're incrementing `j` in that loop, you need to check if `j` is below the upper bound of the array, rather than comparing with zero.

```
while (i >= 0 && j < size)
```

This will also make use of the `size` parameter, which is currently unused.  If you compile with a sufficiently high warning level, the compiler would tell you that `size` is an unused parameter which would be a clue that something is amiss.